# Deploy Qt 5.6 onto rPi2 with Jessie

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-jessie, qt

I am working on a Qt project for my pi and I have successfully managed to follow this guide to set up a tool chain from Ubuntu to the Rpi:

https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS

However, now I am having troubles deploying qt programs onto the rpi. On the guide, I followed these steps to put a example on the pi, but I have been unable to recreate it with my files:

> 9. Build an example:

```
cd qtbase/examples/opengl/qopenglwidget (the example in a folder)
~/raspi/qt5/bin/qmake
make
scp qopenglwidget pi@IP:/home/pi
```

I have also tried this but I can't seem to figure out how to get the files on the pi. I can find them on my laptop however, so I know they are being created just not put where I want.

> > Once Qt is on the device, Qt Creator can be set up to build, deploy, run and debug Qt apps directly on the device with one click.

```
Go to Options -> Devices
  Add
    Generic Linux Device
    Enter IP address, user & password
    Finish

Go to Options -> Compilers
  Add
    GCC
    Compiler path: ~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++

Go to Options -> Debuggers
  Add
    ~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb

Go to Options -> Qt Versions
  Check if an entry with ~/raspi/qt5/bin/qmake shows up. If not, add it.

Go to Options -> Build & Run
  Kits
    Add
      Generic Linux Device
      Device: the one we just created
      Sysroot: ~/raspi/sysroot
      Compiler: the one we just created
      Debugger: the one we just created
      Qt version: the one we saw under Qt Versions
      Qt mkspec: leave empty
```

Any guidance would be extremely helpful.

I also am using a PiScreen touchscreen and so need the program to come out of the GPIOs and not the HDMI. I read that I need to set QT_QPA_EGLFS_FB to /dev/fb1, but am unsure where to do that. Under 'Run Environment' of the 'Build and Run' I found a system environment section. Would this be the correct spot to add it?

Thanks a bunch